# An issue with a variable in adb shell

Tags: bash, shell, adb

In bash, when I type:

```
$ echo 1 | while read L; do echo $L; done
```

Obviously I got 1 as a result.

Within adb shell, I got the same result.

However, if I type as follows:

```
$ adb shell "echo 1 | while read L; do echo $L; done"
```

I got nothing!

Is there anyone who knows why I got nothing in the above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have got a newline from the `adb` shell.  The trouble is that the shell invoking the `adb shell "… echo $L; …` line saw the `$L` and expanded it to the empty string, so the `adb shell` saw the command line:

```
echo 1 | while read L; do echo; done
```

Use single quotes:

```
adb shell 'echo 1 | while read L; do echo $L; done'
```

Alternatively, get inventive:

```
L='$L'
adb shell "echo 1 | while read L; do echo $L; done"
```

Now the invoking shell replaces the `$L` with `$L` and everything works as intended (but rather coincidentally).